# django admin - get object's language from i18n - *not* the current language of admin

Tags: django, django-admin

In admin page, I am listing all Videos objects. The thing is, videos are in different languages.

I put a button in admin listpage for each video row which should open the video in new tab.

I use i18n. the currect admin page is in "de". but video inside it is in "en". so when I hover the button, I see this link:

```
www.mywebsite.com/de/en/video-title-blabla/1234/
```

I get this link thru `get_absolute_url` of Video model.

how can I remove the current language `/de/` and get video's real url inside admin?

Answer (score 0):

I just did

```
from django.utils.translation import activate

def get_absolute_url(self):
    activate(self.lang)
    return reverse('video', kwargs = {'slug':self.slug, 'vid':self.id})
```

and it worked!